# Clearing the hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, cleanup

I have Ubuntu installed on an old pc and want to wipe the hard drive so I can sell it.
Any suggestions without having to burn a cd? (it doesn't work...)

Comment: Plug it to another computer and wipe it. If you have a laptop there are adapters to connect it throught usb

Answer (score 1):

Using your Ubuntu installation media (USB since optical drive doesn't work), boot up and choose try Ubuntu.

Identify the drive by issuing the command `sudo fdisk -l`

once you've identified it you can choose one of the following options (in both cases change X to the drive designation obtained using the above command) :

**Option 1**

`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`
and on completion
`sync`

Note: You can substitute /dev/random or /dev/urandom for /dev/zero  in the above command if you prefer what some consider a more secure method.

/dev/random should be suitable for uses that need very high quality randomness such as one-time pad or key generation. When the entropy pool is empty, reads from /dev/random will block until additional environmental noise is gathered. A read from the /dev/urandom device will not block waiting for more entropy and for this reason is likely to be faster than /dev/random.

This process can take quite a while and will produce no progress report until it's complete.

It's useful to note that you may be able to speed up the process by setting a larger block size with the bs or obs options. For more details on these and other available options see `man dd`

Option2
If you want a progress report install dc3dd

`sudo apt-get install dc3dd`

then issue the command

`sudo dc3dd wipe=/dev/sdX` `dc3dd` will provide output throughout the process on speed and completion.

The wipe option defaults to using zeros, but can be modified with the following switches for those who believe that overwriting with a pattern is preferable.

pat=HEX              Use pattern as input, writing HEX to every byte
                    of the output. This option can only be used once
                    and cannot be combined with if=, ifs=, or
                    tpat=.
tpat=TEXT            Use text pattern as input, writing the string TEXT
                    repeatedly to the output. This option can only be
                    used once and cannot be combined with if=, ifs=,
                    or pat=.

dc3dd doesn't appear to install a man page by default, for more information on this program see one of the following pages:

http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/dc3dd/

https://plus.google.com/+KarlBernard/posts/CFzGx6kNaHR

Comment: Why `/dev/random`? `/dev/urandom` should be enough and also much faster. I'd even argue that `/dev/zero` is completely sufficient. It's also better to tell `dd` to use a larger block size than 512 bytes. `bs=8M` should work much faster on pretty much every modern HDD.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Points taken. Option 2 - The dc3dd wipe command defaults to using zeros without the pat or tpat options. I feel that is sufficient for my purposes as well. Other options are available for those who disagree. Improved answer.